# Eclipse Kepler does not show suggestion

Tags: eclipse, java-8, ubuntu-14.04, eclipse-kepler, eclipse-jdt

I am using Kepler eclipse with java8 and ubuntu 14.04 .Eclipse show me suggestion java predefined class and methods.But it does not show suggestion of classes/method declared by me.I have search and found solution that Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced' and set default . But it is not helpful for me.It show me all suggestion including jar class and method. But it is not show suggestion for my application class and method or  variable of any class.

Comment: Check once in  Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Favorites --> Restore Default

Comment: @ArdeshanaMilan this is not working for me

Comment: Have you tried rebooting? I had this issue once with an older eclipse and restarting my laptop fixed it.

Comment: I suggest you show the actual details of your classes and project. There may be a perfectly good reason why it's not showing the completions you expect.

Comment: you should really consider updating your eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Upgrading eclipse worked.